# Zoe, 19 months old cat, British Shorthair, refusing to eat due to digestive issues

Tags: cats, health, feeding, diseases, veterinarian

Greetings to all members of the cats community,

I am truly desperate for any help or guidance you’d be able to offer.

3 days ago my cat lost her interest in food and started vomiting and I took her to the Vet for a check up.

Firstly he measured her internal body temperature, then he ran blood tests, an X-Ray and started treating her with antibiotics. Also he put her on a diet for 15 hours and afterwards she has been refusing to eat, apart from drinking only water. According to the Vet her gut flora was disrupted and colon peristalsis. Somehow she may have come into contact with a bacteria eventhough she is an indoor cat and has no contact whatsoever with other pets.

However her vomiting stopped the next day in the evening, but she didn’t want to eat. Yesterday she was also given a Ringer solution 60 ml with a Vit C+B complex, in case to be hydrated. Her last bowel movement was 79 hours ago, but the main problem is that she is refusing to eat everything, her dry/wet food, homemade chicken broth, chicken lungs, etc. The last thing that she ate today is a tuna soup leaving the chunks of tuna aside, also anything with meat chunks in it she refuses to eat.

She is drinking only water and she has been urinating but the most concerning part is that she is unable to have a bowel movement. It may be because she hasn’t eaten properly but I have no idea what else should I try to encourage her to eat.

I've also noticed that she is standing often in a certain (see the picture attached) that I am assuming she might have a tummy ache, eventhough most of the time she is acting as usual.

If anyone had a similar experience with their cat/pet please let me know.

[image: cats'recent posture]

Comment: When have you last spoken to the vet? Does the vet know that your cat didn't pass stool for so long? If not, please call them first and ask them for advice. They are far more likely to be able to help you than a bunch of strangers on the internet.

Comment: it is normal for a cat to pass stool every day and to pee 2-3 times  every day, changes in this and it is time to talk to your vet.a cat treated with antibiotics do often get loose stool during and for some time after the treatment.

Comment: @Elmy yesterday I've spoken last to the vet, and since Saturday we have been for treatment every other day. I was told that taking into consideration that she didn't eat properly thus she couldn't pass stool and the maximum time is 5 days. He's also recommended that I should give her cold pressed olive oil as a natural laxative. However today we have an appointment and I'll make sure she'll be offered the required treatment. Also thanks a lot for taking the time to offer your insight!

Comment: @trondhansen thank you for your response. I've been in contact with the vet every day, and every other day we went for treatment. It has occurred to me as well since the same happens with humans when they're on antibiotics, but today I will mention this at the vet and ask to take any required measures and offer her the right treatment.

Comment: @Selda It's important that the vet knows about both problems - that she doesn't eat and that she doesn't pass stool. Both problems can be linked, but it's important to know which is the cause. Does she not have bowel movement because she didn't eat and her bowels are empty or does she refuse to eat because her bowels are blocked and she simply cannot digest any more solid food. Both problems can be fatal and I suggest you insist that the vet explains the situation to you and (if she's constipated) administers potent laxatives or (if she refuses food) feeds her via IV.

Comment: @Elmy I can assure you that the vet has been notified accordingly, the X-ray images didn't show of any kind of blockage, her bowels were partially empty and he told me to wait a bit longer. However this morning she was able to eat two tea spoonfools of wet food finally, and as I am writing to you she has been able ta pass stool :). Anyhow I am still sending her for her last check up today as I want to discuss with the vet every single detail including the ones that you've mentioned. Many thanks!

Comment: @Selda That is great news! Maybe it was just a stomach flu and the antibiotics have taken effect. I hope she'll be better very soon.

Comment: @Elmy Thank you, you're too kind. I am suspecting the same, hope she'll recover soon. Take care and all the best!